# Python 3.5.0 can't install anything through pip version 7.1.2

Tags: python, macos

When I try to install anything with (for example) `python3 -m pip install numpy` , I get

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for numpy
```

I've tried upgrading pip3 with `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` but have only gotten

```
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages
```

and  when I do `python3 -m pip --version` I get

```
pip 7.1.2 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
```

I'm unable to install any modules at all. Any advice? I am on MacOS.

Comment: Is that helping you? --> https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/11447

Comment: It's not a numpy specific issue. No matter what I try to install, it gives the exact same error.

Comment: what if you leave off python3 -m, and just do `pip3 install numpy`

Comment: @d_kennetz that's correct.

Comment: @d_kennetz it gives the exact same: Collecting numpy
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for numpy

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, I suggest you use **brew** as the **package manager** and install python, not as binary from the python.org but binary using brew (https://brew.sh), I hope it'll fix your troubles, during the installation process.

1. Install **brew** package manager:

   $ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
2. Install "**python3**" on your machine (***python2*** can be installed in the same way):

   $ brew install python3
3. Check what version of python you are using:

   $ which python3

   **Output**(*should look like*): `/usr/local/bin/python3`
4. Check what pip you are using:

   $ which pip3

   **Output**(*should look like*): `/usr/local/bin/pip3`
5. Then you can **install any package using "pip"**:

   $ pip3 install virtualenv
6. **Verify that package was installed**:

   $ pip3 freeze | grep virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

Update pip manually, first download pip:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

and then run the command

```
python3 get-pip.py
```

Now you can install with pip3

```
pip3 install numpy
```